# Python Tkinter - Opening multiple files using ttk.Notebook and tkinter.Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having the following issue, that I am trying to add a feature having multiple files opened at once. This is known to be possible with `tkinter.ttk.Notebook`. Each tab is a `ttk.Frame`. Now I also have a `tkinter.Text` (the code of the user, it's a text editor) and I'm trying to add it. But it doesn't take that argument (Frame). This is the code I have right now:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
from pyedit.main import TextEditor

class Files:
    def __init__(self, master) -> None:

        self.master = master
        self.tabbar = ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.tabbar.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.update_file)

    def add_file(self, filename) -> None:
        tab = ttk.Frame(self.tabbar)

        if filename is None:
            name = "Untitled"
            self.tabbar.add(tab, text=name)

        else:
            self.tabbar.add(tab, text=filename)

        self.tabbar.pack(expand=1, fill="BOTH")

        self.texteditor = TextEditor(self.master, filename)
        self.texteditor.open_file()

    def update_file(self, event) -> None:
        filename = self.get_file()
        self.texteditor.bar.current_file = filename

    def get_file(self) -> str:
        return self.tabbar.tab(self.tabbar.select(), "text")
```

And this is the initializing, `CustomText` being a subclass of `tkinter.Text` but with line numbers:

```py
self.text = CustomText(
            self.master,
            yscrollcommand=self.y_scrollbar.set,
            xscrollcommand=self.x_scrollbar.set,
            highlightcolor="white",
            wrap=NONE,
            undo=True
        )
```

```py
class TextEditor(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, tab) -> None:
        super().__init__(master)

        self.master = master
        self.filename = filename
        self.tab = tab
        self.line_numbers = TextLineNumbers(self, width=20)
        self.syntax = Syntax(master)
        self.add_scrollbar()

    def add_scrollbar(self) -> None:
        self.y_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.tab)
        self.x_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.tab, orient="horizontal")
        self.y_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.x_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.line_numbers.pack(side="left", fill=Y)

        self.text = CustomText(
            self.tab,
            yscrollcommand=self.y_scrollbar.set,
            xscrollcommand=self.x_scrollbar.set,
            highlightcolor="white",
            wrap=NONE,
            undo=True
        )

        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, side=RIGHT, expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self.on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self.on_change)
        self.text.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.on_key_release)

        self.y_scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.x_scrollbar.config(command=self.text.xview)
        self.line_numbers.attach(self.text)
```

This is the TextEditor class where I am creating the text boxes. These should be created on each tab. On the same file (`main.py`) I have a `run` function

```py
def run(filename) -> None:
    root = Tk()
    root.title("PyEdit")
    syntax = Syntax(root)
    syntax.load_colors()
    old_colors = syntax.colors
    files = Files(root)
    tab = files.add_file(None)
    texteditor = TextEditor(root, filename, tab)
    texteditor.pack(side="top", fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    texteditor.add_toolbar()
    root.mainloop()
    if old_colors != syntax.colors:
        syntax.save_colors()
```

Here is my first attempt adding a tab.

Comment: _"But it doesn't take that argument (Frame)."_ - why do you think that? If you are getting an error, please include the full error in your question. If you aren't getting an error, please describe what it's doing and how it's different from what you expect.

Comment: Do you mean I should the Frame rather than master?

Comment: I don't know, because your original question is unclear. You claimed something doesn't take a frame argument, but none of the posted code takes or is given a frame parameter. You haven't shown any error messages, and the code you posted can't run because it's missing pieces.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how I could implement multiple files in my current [text editor](https://github.com/YodaPY/PyEdit).

Comment: I understand that, but you've claimed you're having a specific problem, yet haven't shown any error messages or told us what code is causing the problem. You've shown code that uses a class (`TextEditor`) that you haven't defined, and you've shown a class (`CustomText`) that you don't use. How are we supposed to make sense of this?

Comment: Yeah, I do not know where I should actually connect the `tkinter.Text` with the Frame. I followed [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-tabbed-widget-with-python-tkinter/) guide, but now Im having difficulties implementing that in my own system, as they work with Labels and I work with `tkinter.Text`

Comment: You can find all classes in the repo

Comment: Your question needs to include a [mcve]. Links to code on other sites is discouraged.

Comment: Well, all files are connected to each other. I'm not sure I could post code without breaking the complete logic

Comment: Added the TextEditor class

Comment: You still haven't explained why you think your code isn't working. If you're getting an error, you need to include that in your question. If you aren't getting an error, you need to describe what it's doing and how that's different from what you expect. All you've said is _"it doesn't take that argument (Frame)"_ without describing what "it" is or why you think it doesn't take an argument.

Comment: No, I do not get an error. "It" is in this case the CustomText (CustomText is a subclass of `Text`) which just adds the line numbers. Currently its not showing any tabs. I am expecting a tab "Untitled" or whatever the user gave as argument when he run `python -m predict [filename]`. At the end, I want to be able to click on any tab and its file content will appear as well as create a new tab when opening files with the toolbar "open" button, each file has a different tab. It's doing nothing of that.

Comment: I'll ask one final time: why do you think _"it doesn't take that argument"_? It looks like it takes it to me.

Comment: I have tried it replacing `self.master` with the Frame I made that I added to the tabbar. It still doesn't work

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that I asked.

Comment: I do not know why I thought that. But asking that question over and over again does not help me at all as it's not really important right now

Comment: It's not important? It's the central part of your question.

Comment: "Why did you think it wouldn't take that argument" is not the central part of my question

Comment: The central part of my question is how I am able to add those tabs with the correct Text and Scrollbars and everything it had before, just for multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't run the code you provided, I can only guess at the problem. One thing that looks very wrong is this line of code:

```
self.texteditor = TextEditor(self.master, filename)
```

You created a new tab immediately prior to that, so you should be putting the text editor in `tab` rather than in `self.master`. You also need to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the text editor so that it's visible in the tab:

```
self.texteditor = TextEditor(tab, filename)
self.texteditor.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Also, since you're creating multiple text editors it makes no sense to store it in `self.texteditor` since that will get overwritten each time you create a new tab. You can just store it as a local variable, and/or append it to a list of editors.

Another problem is this line:

```
self.text = CustomText(
            self.tab,
            ...
```

You should not be putting `CustomText` in `self.tab`. It needs to be in `self`. As a rule, if you're subclassing `Frame` and adding widgets, all additional widgets need to go in `self` or a descendant.

Another problem I see is that you're calling `self.tabbar.pack(expand=1, fill="BOTH")` every time you add a file. You only need to call that once when you actually create `self.tabbar`.

These probably aren't the only problems, but since you didn't provide a working example I can only go by what I can see in the posted code.